# More than 1 appointment on the same day for a patient and display both appointments

Tags: sql

I am trying to find patients that have more than 1 appointment on the same day. I want to then display all the appointments the patient may have. Do I need to use a subquery to do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
Select
  Appt.ID-PatNm as Patient,
  ApptNum,
  Sched_ApptType.Prov.Mnemonic as Type,
  Appt.Provider-Name as Provider, 
  Appt.Dt, 
  Appt.Tm,
  Appt.Department-Mnemonic As Dept,
  Appt.SchedulerInits,
  Case $EXTRACT(Appt.InternalStatus,1)
    when 'P' then 'Pending'
    when 'A' then 'Arrived' 
    when 'R' then 'Rescheduled'
  End as Status
From Sched.Appointment Appt 
JOIN Sched_ApptType.Prov ON
  Appt.Department = Sched_ApptType.Prov.Department
  and
  Appt.Provider =  Sched_ApptType.Prov.Provider
  and
  Appt.Type = Sched_ApptType.Prov.ApptType
Where (Appt.Dt) > DATEADD('DD',-120,CURRENT_DATE)
  AND Appt.InternalStatus IN ('P','R','A')
  AND Appt.Department-Mnemonic= 'EYE'
Group By 
  Appt.ID-PatNm,
  Appt.Dt
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Since you have some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Just a remark: It is strange to see `ID-PatNm`, `Provider-Name`, and `Department-Mnemonic`. They look like subtractions, but I assume they are supposed to be column names, right? Does your DBMS allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You get the patients having more than one appointment in a day by grouping by patient and day:

```
select distinct a.id_patnm
from sched.appointment a 
group by a.id_patnm, a.dt
having count(*) > 1
```

So yes, you need a subquery:

```
Where (Appt.Dt) > DATEADD('DD',-120,CURRENT_DATE)
  AND Appt.InternalStatus IN ('P','R','A')
  AND Appt.Department_Mnemonic= 'EYE'
  AND Appt.ID_PatNm IN
  (
    select a.id_patnm
    from sched.appointment a 
    group by a.id_patnm, a.dt
    having count(*) > 1
  )
```

(BTW: I used `id_patnm` instead of `id-patnm` here, for I don't know any DBMS that would allow the hyphen. When using a hyphen in a column name you have to use quotes on the name, e.g. `"id-patnm"`.)

Comment: Thank you Thorsten for the tips. That is the syntax. I tried running the query, but received an error that says Input(where) encountered after end of query. It is not letting me have the having count(*) > 1 before the Where.

Comment: No, `having` is after `group by` and `group by` is after `where`. If you want to add a where clause to the subquery then have it before `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could add a column for Appointment_id which would then allow you to get the desired result.